# ZXing barcode scanner inside a dialog fragment

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I want to create a DialogFragment that will contain barcode scanner preview and will handle the scan result and return it back to the activity.

This is my current code. Everything works fine but whene the scanner decodes any code the application closes (no error is thrown).

```
public class ScanFragment extends DialogFragment implements DialogInterface.OnKeyListener {
    private final Context context;

    private FragmentScanBinding binding;

    private CaptureManager capture;
    private IResultCallback callback;

    public ScanFragment(Context context, IResultCallback callback) {
        this.context = context;
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentScanBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());

        binding.btnCancel.setOnClickListener(view -> dismiss());

        BarcodeView view = binding.getRoot().findViewById(R.id.zxing_barcode_surface);
        view.setFramingRectSize(new Size(600, 300));

        capture = new CaptureManager(requireActivity(), binding.zxingBarcodeScanner);
        capture.initializeFromIntent(requireActivity().getIntent(), savedInstanceState);
        capture.setShowMissingCameraPermissionDialog(false);
        capture.decode();

        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        capture.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        capture.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        capture.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        capture.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        capture.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        return (binding.zxingBarcodeScanner).onKeyDown(keyEvent.getKeyCode(), keyEvent);
    }
}
```

I would also like to bind my IResultCallback to the result of CaptureManager but I simply dont know how to bind it to camera.

Comment: From the documentation for `CaptureManager`: _"This is intended for an Activity that is dedicated to capturing a single barcode and returning it via setResult(). For other use cases, use DefaultBarcodeScannerView or BarcodeView directly"_.

Answer (score 0):

So the best solution for me was to implement my own `CaptureManager` and make it so it doesn't work for Activities but instead, it works with callback functions that are passed into the constructor. I also had to implement another initialization function since I don't use intents.